# How do I instruct the browser to open at a specific size?

Tags: browser

Is there a way to tell the browser to open the page at some dimension other than full screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript. There is:

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

or:

```
window.resizeTo( w,h )
```

Comment: Forgive the noob question: in the second example do I put numerical values only for width and height (480,120) or is it like (w480,h120)?